# How do you set only the image width of a Wordpress thumbnail

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set the width of a post thumbnail using:

```php
the_post_thumbnail()
```

The width of the image needs to be `210px` but the height is not meant to be fixed as all the images will be different sizes. I have tried:

```php
the_post_thumbnail( array( 210, 0 ) )
```

But this does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Add this inside your functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 210, 9999 ); //210 pixels wide (and unlimited height)

}
```

Use it inside your theme's template files

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); } ?>
```

For default thumbnail add this inside your functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 9999 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}
```

**Reference:** [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

Answer (score 2):

Change `the_post_thumbnail(array(210,0))` to `the_post_thumbnail(array(210,9999))`

Answer (score -1):

Open your themes functions.php file and add your image size:

**Example:**

```
add_image_size('slider', 525, 339, true);
```

**Breakdown of the code:**

- `'slider'`= The name of the new image size (use this when adding the new image size to your template file).
- `525` = The image width
- `339` = The image height
- `true` = The image will be cropped to the exact dimensions listed.

**Usage:**
Use a current template (index.php, single.php, etc.), or create your own. Place this inside the loop (usually just after `the_title();`) **:**

```
the_post_thumbnail('slider');
```

Now when you add a page or post that uses the template you added the code above, use the featured image option to upload an image. It will output to the size you've created.

**Note:**
This will only apply to newly uploaded images.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this : [Thumbnail Custom Size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24202/the-post-thumbnail-custom-sizes-not-display-correctly)

It is the best way to change Thumbnail Size.

Comment: This should be a comment as it is a link only response.