# Wordpress theme/image management

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I've been creating a custom responsive theme in Wordpress and I've hit a wall when it comes to image management. I'd like to style images in a way that wordpress doesn't seem to inherently support - I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

with the images added via the regular wordpress media management pane, and inserted into posts/pages. The images should be out of the flow of the content but accurately placed next to the correct headers/text blocks. Most importantly, the images ought to collapse into a column with the rest of the content at the correct media query breakpoints.

Here's what I've tried, from worst to best:

1. Hard coded images in template files

   - Obviously the worst option. Not portable, requires a lot of meddling, and would be almost impossible to align the images with the correct content. Also, no real way of making the images responsive with the content.
2. Use the default image styling and abandon the idea of pulling the images out of the regular flow

   - Non optimal, but it would allow anyone to change/edit images easily.
3. Remove images from the results of the_content(), then place and style them separate.

   - Portable, but has the same problems as #1 - difficult to align the images with content and keep responsiveness.
4. Use the featured image on pages that only require one image

   - Pretty good option for pages that need ONLY one image, but there is no easy way to make the featured image an arbitrary size/aspect ratio.
5. Use markup in the editor to correctly layout the images

   - Requires anyone editing the posts/pages to have some knowledge of the underlying theme. This seems to work the best, but it isn't portable (might break stuff on theme change).
   - While I've had the best results with this option, it seems sort of antithetical to using a cms/wysiwyg editor in the first place.

My question is whether or not the last option really is the best to get the result I want?

Comment: I'd propose an [option](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/32994) that extends #4, but I don't understand the size/ratio issue.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739968/how-do-you-set-only-the-image-width-of-a-wordpress-thumbnail/9740059#9740059), it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the answer was clearly custom fields, and none of the other options I listed. With the advanced custom fields plugin, it becomes a breeze to do what I wanted. You don't need the plugin, but it makes image management a whole lot easier, as it fully integrates the wordpress media library with the custom field (which you would have to do manually otherwise). With the plugin, custom fields meet all of my needs (responsiveness, portability, and ease of use for the technically challenged).